# Float button into form/container

Tags: html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMQA1.jpg

New to coding and want to add a search bar with a search button. Not sure why, but the button is below the bar and not to the right. Trying to follow this:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_searchbar3 but just for the search bar. I tried using the exact values and code as that, then started tinkering with different values because it didn't work for some reason.
Here is my code:

```
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a class="active" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com/"><i class="far fa-comments"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-video"></i></a>
  <a href="#"><i class="far fa-user-circle"></i></a>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>


.icon-bar {
  width: 100%; /* Full-width */
  background-color: #555; /* Dark-grey background */
  overflow: hidden; /* Overflow due to float [auto] */
}

.icon-bar a {
  float: left; /* Float links side by side */
  display: block;
  text-align: center; /* Center-align text */
  width: 10%; /* Equal width (5 icons with 20% width each = 100%) */
  padding: 10px 0; /* Some top and bottom padding */
  transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Add transition for hover effects */
  color: white; /* White text color  ALSO THE PROBLEM*/
  font-size: 36px; /* Increased font size THIS IS THE PROBLEM*/
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000; /* Add a hover color */
}

.icon-bar a.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D; /* Add an active/current color */
}



.icon-bar .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.icon-bar input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-left: -10;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
}

.icon-bar .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-left: none;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:  12%;
}


.icon-bar .search-container button:hover {
  background: #555;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .icon-bar .search-container {
    float: none;
  }
  .icon-bar a, .icon-bar input[type=text], .icon-bar .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 14px;
  }
  .icon-bar input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;  
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems that the input is taking the whole size of the search-container div. If you increase the with, you will see the difference. Try this: <div class="search-container" style="width: 271px;">

Comment: It is not anyhow the correct solution but it explains the problem you are facing

Comment: this is a very concrete solution from W3School. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_search_button

Comment: These are other options as well. https://tippingpoint.dev/search-icon-inside-input
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.mysub{
background-color: lightgreen;
position: absolute;
right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<form>
<label>Name_:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="search...">
<br>
<input type="submit" class="mysub">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: If I use an absolute position, would it interfere if different devices are used?